# Select lead_id's where other column has duplicates as well

Tags: mysql, count

I have a database table looking like this:

```
lead_id  ||  user_id  ||  action_form
   1     ||     56    ||      seen
   2     ||     56    ||      sent
   2     ||     49    ||      sent
 ....    ||    ....   ||      ....
```

Currently I am running the query

```
SELECT lead_id, 
       Count(*) 
FROM   creat_rg_lead_company 
GROUP  BY lead_id 
HAVING Count(*) > 3;
```

which is returning all lead_id's which are present more then 3 times.
But I only want to SELECT the lead_id's which have the action_form 'sent' more then 3 times.

I want these leads to give a seperate class to hide them from other visitors.
Thanks for the assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand your question, you need a where statement in the query

```
SELECT lead_id, count(*) 
FROM creat_rg_lead_company 
WHERE action_form='sent' 
GROUP BY lead_id 
HAVING count(*) > 3;
```

This way you only count the numer of times the action_form is sent.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/15856/2)